# Create extra relocatable section in GNU linker script

Tags: c, linker, arm, gnu, linker-scripts

I'm trying to create an extra ram section (in my GNU linker script) for initialized data, in my ARM MCU. The section will have to be placed at a known address, so that I can set specific attributes for it in the MPU. 
I'm having some trouble with all the linker magic.

The memory is divided as follows:

```
/* Memory Spaces Definitions */
MEMORY
{
  rom (rx)  :         ORIGIN = 0x00420200, LENGTH = 0x001DFE00
  ram (rwx) :         ORIGIN = 0x20400000, LENGTH = 0x0005e000
  ram_nocache_section (rwx) : ORIGIN = 0x2045e000, LENGTH = 0x00002000
  sdram(rwx):         ORIGIN = 0x70000000, LENGTH = 0x00200000
}
```

It's the "ram_nocache_section" that I'm trying to handle.

I can define an appropriate section as follows:

```
/* no cache section */
.ram_nocache :
{
   . = ALIGN(8);
   *(.ram_nocache)
} > ram_nocache_section
```

This works, but the resulting binary is gigantic. 0.5 GB. This is because the ram address space is 0.5 GB apart from the flash address space. The way to deal with this, is to 'relocate' the initialized ram data. The script performs this like so:

```
.text :
{
    ...
} > rom

. = ALIGN(4);
_etext = .;

.relocate : AT (_etext)
{
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _srelocate = .;
    *(.ramfunc .ramfunc.*);
    *(.data .data.*);
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _erelocate = .;
} > ram
```

This will magically allocate initialized data (and ram functions) *both* in flash and in ram. So this would be easy just to copy, right? Like so:

```
. = ALIGN(4);
_etext = .;

.relocate : AT (_etext)
{
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _srelocate = .;
    *(.ramfunc .ramfunc.*);
    *(.data .data.*);
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _erelocate = .;
} > ram

. = ALIGN(4);
_eramdata = .;

.relocate2 : AT ( _eramdata )
{
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _srelocate2 = .;
    . = ALIGN(8);
    *(.ram_nocache)
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _erelocate2 = .;
} > ram_nocache_section
```

This will compile, but the resulting binary is still gigantic. This is because the _eramdata symbol is somehow placed in ram and not in flash like the _etext.

Well then... According to this [document](https://community.freescale.com/docs/DOC-101433), I should be able to do something like this instead:

```
.relocate2 : AT ( _etext + SIZEOF(.data) + SIZEOF(.ramfunc) )
{
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _srelocate2 = .;
    . = ALIGN(8);
    *(.ram_nocache)
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _erelocate2 = .;
} > ram_nocache_section
```

This wont compile though. Instead I can create the desired result like so:

```
.relocate2 : AT ( _etext + 10k )
{
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _srelocate2 = .;
    . = ALIGN(8);
    *(.ram_nocache)
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _erelocate2 = .;
} > ram_nocache_section
```

However, this is a rather fragile and wasteful solution.

How do I do this properly? I want to place the 'relocate2' section right next to the regular 'relocate' section. Without any excess waste or predefined code limits.

Comment: Read about the `NOINIT` attribute.

Comment: I'm guessing that NOINIT is similar to NOLOAD. Which will prevent any initialization of variables. This will solve the issue (I've checked) but it'll also break the program. (I'm using initialized data.)

Comment: Not clear what you want then. Why not use the standard `.data` section then? And you don't have a load memory specified.

Comment: I want to create a section different from .data at a specified address (so that I can remove some cache attributes etc.)

Answer (score 2):

I like this construct better:

```
. = ALIGN(4);
_etext = .;

.relocate : 
{
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _srelocate = .;
    *(.ramfunc .ramfunc.*);
    *(.data .data.*);
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _erelocate = .;
} > ram AT>rom

.relocate2 :
{
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _srelocate2 = .;
    . = ALIGN(8);
    *(.ram_nocache)
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _erelocate2 = .;
} > ram_nocache_section AT>rom
```

Both sections have to changed to AT>rom. (No mixing.)

Answer (score 0):

I might have found the solution myself:

```
.relocate2 : AT ( _etext + SIZEOF(.relocate) )
{
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _srelocate2 = .;
    . = ALIGN(8);
    *(.ram_nocache)
    . = ALIGN(4);
    _erelocate2 = .;
} > ram_nocache_section
```

I was sure that I'd already tried something like that. But this seems to be what I'd wanted. Still not the most elegant solution though.

Comment: You can use [`AT>rom`](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.20/ld/Output-Section-LMA.html) to place the LMA of these initialized sections.  You need some simple assembler and some LMA labels to do a `memcpy()` of the LMA source to the init destination (either way).  Then the linker will do this addition for you (same for `_etext`).  An alternative way to do this is put everything in `_etext`, but provide padding for the MMU/MPU.  This will result in the binary having an extra padding size though.

Comment: I did try the AT>rom but the linker complained about overlapping sections. Apparently the "AT>rom" and "section : AT ( ... )" construct is conflicting with each other. I just tried to change both to AT>rom though. That seems to work. (I'll post the code below.)

Comment: It's not a bad idea to put all in .text either. (It would create a kind of 'this is flash' section.)